# Number theory - Modulo

Tags: number-theory

(3.1)

Let a, b, k, m be integers such that k, m > 0.

Suppose that a^k=b^k (mod m) and that a^(k+1)=b^(k+1) (mod m)

(3.1)

Then these two assumptions are not enough to imply that a=b (mod m).

Indeed, take m = a = 4 and b = 2.

Then 4^2=2^2 (mod 4) and 4^3=2^3 (mod 4) but 4 != 2 (mod 4).

What condition would you add to (3.1) so that your condition together with (3.1) would imply that
a=b(mod m)?

Prove your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that if $a^k\equiv b^k\pmod{m}$ and $a^{k+1}\equiv b^{k+1}\pmod{m}$ and $a$ and $m$ are *relatively prime*, then $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$.

Added: From the two given congruences, by multiplication we get $$a^kb^{k+1}\equiv a^{k+1}b^k\pmod{m}.\tag{1}$$
Show that if $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime, then $b$ and $m$ are relatively prime, and use (1) to finish.

Comment: I tried this, and  i think it's wrong.
What if you take:
a=3
b=4
m=7
Then, 3^2=4^2 (mod 7) and 3^3=4^3 (mod 7), but 3 !=4 (mod 7)
and as you said, the numbers 3 and 7 are relatively prime.
Correct me if I'm wrong..
Thanks!

Comment: Note that $3^3\not\equiv 4^3\pmod{7}$. For $64-27=37$.

Comment: @Katerina 3*2 is 6 mod 7 while 4*2 is 1 mod 7 which are quite different to my mind.